# Read a file in bash and for each line perfome copy and maintain sequence

Tags: bash, shell, readfile, file-copying

I have txt file contains names of jar , I want to read this txt file and for each line I want to find and move jar with same name and version number appended (version number is subject to change) from a folder X to  folder JarSequence.
Text file is jar.txt which has -

- bbb
- aaa
- ccc

now for each line in txt file I want to copy jar in  folder JarSequence so that  folder JarSequence has -

- bbb-1.0.1.jar
- aaa-1.0.1.jar
- ccc-1.0.1.jar

If possible I also want to maintain same sequence in JarSequence folder  as in text file.

Thanks for any help .

Comment: ccc has 1.0.2 whereas the others have 1.0.1. Is that intentional?

Comment: If intentional, how do you determine whether to append `"-1.0.2.jar"` instead of `"-1.0.1.jar"`??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry version number is  same for each jar(updated the Question).But I need it varies  when I move from one build to another but still same for all jars.
e.g  aaa- ${buildNumber}.jar 
       bbb-${buildNumber}.jar
we have buildNumber stored in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="your_txt_file"
suffix="-1.0.1.jar"

while IFS= read -r jarfile
do
    #echo "$jarfile"
    mv "$jarfile" JarSequence/"$jarfile"${suffix}
done < $file
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, will it retain the sequence as well same it is being copied ?

Comment: if this just tags on *the same text* (suffix) at the end of each filename, then yes, it will retain the same order.

Comment: Always test scripts like this. I usually do: `echo mv "$jarfile" JarSequence/"$jarfile"${suffix}` and execute the script, just to see what would be executed (a sort of 'dry-run'). If that looks good, I remove the echo and run the script.

Comment: But note that this will create `JarSequence/ccc-1.0.1.jar`, not `JarSequence/ccc-1.0.2.jar`. In other words, suffix is *static* in this script.  If you need the suffix to vary *within* the execution of the script, things become more complex.

Comment: thanks @Roadowl, Sorry I have corrected the question every jar will have same version (build number).
yes I need suffix to be varied, I need to pass to the script.

Comment: suffix is basically release build number which should append to every jar and provided at run time.